# Using templated arguments in Dataflow to build dynamic Datastore query

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have Apache Beam pipeline that reads data from Google Cloud Datastore. Pipeline is ran in Google Cloud Dataflow in batch mode and it is written in Python.

Problem is with templated argument which I'm trying to use to create Datastore query with dynamic timestamp filter.

Pipeline is defined as follows:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.datastoreio import ReadFromDatastore
from apache_beam.io.gcp.datastore.v1new.types import Query

class UserOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_value_provider_argument('--filter', type=int)

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions()

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:

    user_options = pipeline_options.view_as(UserOptions)

    data = (p
        | 'Read' >> ReadFromDatastore(build_query(user_options.filter.get()))
        | ...
```

And `build_query` function as follows:

```
def build_query(filter):
    return Query(
        kind='Kind',
        filters=[('timestamp', '>', filter)],
        project='Project'
    )
```

Running this leads to error `RuntimeValueProvider(...).get() not called from a runtime context`.

I have also tried `ReadFromDatastore(build_query(user_options.filter))` But then error is `ValueError: (u"Unknown protobuf attr type [while running 'Read/Read']", <class 'apache_beam.options.value_provider.RuntimeValueProvider'>)`.

Everything works just fine if templated argument is removed from equation eg. like this: `ReadFromDatastore(build_query(1563276063))`. So the problem is with using templated argument while building Datastore query.

My guess is that `build_query` should be defined some other way but after spending some time with documentation and googling I still have no idea how.

Any suggestions how I could solve this are highly appreciated!

**EDIT 1**

Actually, in this case filter is always relative to current timestamp so passing it as an argument is probably not even necessary if there is some other way to use dynamic values. Tried with `ReadFromDatastore(build_query(int(time())-90000))` but two consecutive runs contained exactly same filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value providers need to be supported by the source you're using. Only there can it be unpacked at the right moment.

When creating your own source you have full control over this obviously. When using a pre-existing source I only see two options:

1. Provide the value at template creation, meaning don't use a template argument for it
2. Create a PR for the pre-existing source to support template arguments

Comment: Thanks @Dennis! Providing value at template creation sounds suitable since filter value is always relative to current timestamp. However I don't know how to make it dynamic. Tried with `ReadFromDatastore(build_query(int(time())-90000))` but two consecutive runs contained exactly same filter so the value seems to be locked to what it is at template creation time. Any hints on that?

Comment: You're missing some important concepts about creating templates. The Python code for your template runs only once. The pipeline within the python code can run many times. The parameter you are trying to set only gets evaluated once, during template creation, and therefore stays the same for the whole of template's lifetime.
In other words it can't be dynamic. You could only decide to provide a value for it later when executing the dataflow job but this again requires the use of value providers.

Comment: Yeah, that was my understanding before I misunderstood option 1 in your answer. So there is currently no way to do this except by writing my own (or making PR to existing) Datastore source.

Comment: Oh, it turned out that there already is a PR regarding to this: https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/8950